# Where to download LoadRunner 9.10 compatible VuGen

Tags: loadrunner

I have a client with licenses for LoadRunner 9.10.  Anybody know a URL where I can download a compatible VuGen?  A URL requiring a customer number would work.  I could get that from my client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This precise question was asked and answered in the lr-loadrunner google group.   The thread can be found at

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lr-loadrunner/YUa14yp7Yk4

Comment: I had actually answered the question there and no idea about it :D

Comment: My search didn't turn that one up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have this version online (I will check to make sure).
To get it you will need to open a ticket here: http://support.openview.hp.com/

Note that this version is no longer supported so you will be pretty much on your own.

EDIT: I verified and you can get it here: http://support.openview.hp.com/software_updates.jsp with your SAID.

Thanks,
Boris.